# Numpy array with string components

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a numpy array with string components. I have used the below command and it's output is shown.

```
>>> a = np.full((2,2), 'hello', dtype='S5')
>>> a
array([[b'hello', b'hello'],
       [b'hello', b'hello']], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

Can you explain why the array components appear as b'hello' instead of just 'hello'? I was expecting the array to appear as:

```
>>> a
array([['hello', 'hello'],
      ['hello', 'hello']],
     dtype='|S5')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to your `dtype` you could convert to usual string with `bytes.decode`. From [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html):

> `'S'`, `'a'`  (byte-)string

So there are bytestrings and bytestrings are showed with `b` prefix, you could also check type of your elemets:

```
In [206]: type(a[0][0])
Out[206]: numpy.bytes_
```

For converting from `bytes` to `string`:

```
In [189]: [list(map(bytes.decode, i)) for i in a]
Out[189]: [['hello', 'hello'], ['hello', 'hello']]
```

Or you could create your array with `unicode` strings with `U` dtype:

```
a = np.full((2,2), 'hello', dtype='U5')

In [191]: a
Out[191]:
array([['hello', 'hello'],
       ['hello', 'hello']], dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: This is a python3 issue, where strings are normally unicode.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm not sure that it's an issue. It's just another behaviour as I understand.

Comment: The `b` doesn't appear in a python2 display.  A `u` would if the dtype were 'U5'.

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.

Comment: It means bytes. You could read about [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) and [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview) in docs